# Modified Alfresco template (.ftl), changes not appearing on the webpage?

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share

I modified the `document-details.ftl` in `alfresco/tomcat/webapps/share/WEB-INF/classes/alfresco/templates/org/alfresco`
I added a new class to this line:

```
<div class="yui-gc new-class">
```

Restarted Alfresco using alfresco.sh

After reloading the web-page `(/share/page/docment-details?nodeRef=...)` nothing changes. I inspected the page and I cannot find the class anywhere.

What am I missing?

Note: I am running Alfresco on ubuntu

Comment: Are you sure you modified the correct FTL for the page you're looking at? Can you use surfbug to double check?

Comment: which version of alfresco you are using?

Comment: this is not a right way to change in OOTB files.